# Exclude Column From Regression Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-regression

I would like to exlcude "(Intercept)" from the output of my regresison in R, glm.logit

```
betai=coef(glm.logit)
coef(glm.logit)
```

Is what I am seeing actually a matrix, i.e. does coef produce a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

It is a `named` vector if we check the `str` (`str(nm1)`).  We can use `setdiff` to remove only the '(Intercept)' from the `names` and extract with `[`

```
nm1 <- coef(glm.logit)
nm1[setdiff(names(nm1), "(Intercept)")]
```

Answer (score 0):

`coef` returns a named numeric vector. You can remove the `(Intercept)` value based on position.

```
betai <- coef(glm.logit)
betai <- betai[-1]
```